# Чи доречне використання слова "всупір" в діловій мові?

Tags: вживання-слів, синоніми, росіянізм

Існує поєтичний синонім русизму "не дивлячись" - "всупір". Наприклад, він зустрічається у перекладі Стусом Кіплінга. Але крім художніх творів пошук не дає результатів використання цього слова. Чи не є воно занадто специфічним і неприйнятним для ділового використання?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Тлумачний український словник](https://explain_words_uk.academic.ru/1002/%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%80) (2014 р.) все ж містить статтю:

> всупір - наперекір, всупор.
>   Не виводять співаночок на весь двір соловієві на вишенці всупір. [Звн 108]; [ВЛ]

Однак ні в СУМі-20, ні в СУМі-11 цього слова не знайшла. Також не знайшла і в словнику за ред. Б. Грінченка. Лише натрапляла у художній літературі, зокрема в [І. Драча](http://www.ukrcenter.com/%D0%9B%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0/%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%94%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87/65634/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-perpetuum-mobile-%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE-%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96), [І. Франка](http://www.i-franko.name/uk/Verses/ZVershynINyzyn/Vesnjanky/ScheSchebeche.html) та ін.

Отже, у художньому стилі можна використовувати таке слово, однак в науковому, офіційно-діловому стилі все ж НЕ варто.

P. S.: У нас є чудове слово "всупереч", що дещо подібне до "всупір" і є зафіксованим у різноманітних словниках, то чому б не використовувати саме його?

Comment: Зазначу, шчо тоь ж СУМ маʼ наприклад спільнопневе [супірник](http://sum.in.ua/s/supirnyk "Том 9, 1978. — Стор. 847.")

Comment: Цікаво, що це за словник.

Comment: Всупір саме і є скороченим варіантом слова всупереч, тож у діловому стилі його краще не вживати, так само, як і інші скорочення.